# chartjs xaxis data clumbing up y axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This is the result of my graph.

All of the data is right, the issue im facing is since there is data for the same day, its just adding it on top of, or below another point. Is there a way to fix this so the line is an actual line and is not clumped?

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',

  data: {
    datasets: [
{
  label: 'data',
  data: cards,
  borderColor: 'red',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
},
{
  label: 'trendline',
  data: trendLines,
  borderColor: 'blue',
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
}
]

  },
  options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'none',
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
        }
      }
    },
});
```

[image]

Comment: Since you dont provide us with any data structure I assume they are matching on the same  x coordinate, in that case you will need to correct your dataset by combing those values

Comment: If you just have a bunch of data with the same x coordinates, would it look better as a scatter plot? If not, what do you want it to look like?